# File upload with ajax and without upload button

Tags: files, media

Is there any example how to set up form element with type file to upload it via AJAX and without upload button. I want to be same as stackexchange.
[image: upload image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These modules can help you

[HTML5 Drag & Drop File](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragdropfile)

> HTML5 drag & drop + HTML5 file upload with XHR2. Allows the user to
>   drag & drop files into a Image/File Field and uploads it immediately
>   behind the scenes. In theory it should work for as many files as the
>   field allows.
>
> Requires jQuery >= 1.5.2 (jquery_update‎ has that)!
>
> It's a start...
>
> ```
> Enable
> Works for all managed_file fields
> You can disable per field in the field instance config
> ```
>
> There's a settings form under Config > Media where you can change the
>   upload method from Series to Parallel (much faster, but slightly
>   riskier). If you dare, try it out. I've experienced (although not for
>   a while) the full entity form being submitted by a file upload.
>
> If you're uploading A LOT of files, you might encounter the server's
>   max file/POST size limit. I've no solution for that yet.

[Drag'n'Drop Uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads)(you can use dev version,I am using it and work;) )

> The Drag'n'Drop Uploads module adds the ability to drag an image from
>   your local filesystem, drop it onto a node body textarea and have the
>   file automatically uploaded and referenced in your node.

(maybe you just need some custom jquery coding, first hide upload button then fire upload button programmatically in your js)

[Plup](https://www.drupal.org/project/plup)

> Plup module enables uploads to file fields using the popular plupload
>   library. It does not require any other modules to work, but the
>   plupload library must be downloaded separately (version 1.5.8 is the
>   last supported version).
>
> Please note that you must remove the "examples" folder from the
>   downloaded plupload library to avoid introducing a security
>   vulnerability.
>
> The original developer is no longer maintaining the module, and I will
>   only minimally maintain it until Media 2.x has a stable release that
>   works with plupload and multiform, after which I expect to migrate to
>   those modules.

Comment: Good old plupload integration works, too. Is it missing because you don't know it or because you prefer plup?

Comment: Nothing for Drupal 8 ... :-(